# login with linkedin in Ionic 3 mobile app

Tags: cordova, ionic3, linkedin-api

I was using [linkedin cordova plugin](https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-linkedin) for logging in with linkedin account from a while (I developed it last year or more as I remember).
But it stopped working suddenly when I tried to test it these days and it generated me this error message : `{ "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR", "errorMessage": "The passed in mobile identifier is invalid \ "com.mysite.mobile\"" }`

After a quick research I've found that `cordova-plugin-linkedin` is deprecated and from this [`linkedIn` article](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates)

> In addition to the changes listed below, all developers need to migrate to Version 2.0 of our APIs and OAuth 2.0 by May 1.

if I uninstall `cordova-plugin-linkedin` from list of packages since it's using `v1`  what should I use instead .. Or maybe what should I do exactly to make it to work again.

Thanks a lot.